# Clearing APC cache in symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, apc

I cant clear APC cache the output:

```
array(15) { ["num_slots"]=> int(521) ["ttl"]=> int(0) ["num_hits"]=> float(6) ["num_misses"]=> float(2) ["num_inserts"]=> float(65) ["expunges"]=> float(0) ["start_time"]=> int(1367936845) ["mem_size"]=> float(12608) ["num_entries"]=> int(2) ["file_upload_progress"]=> int(1) ["memory_type"]=> string(4) "mmap" ["locking_type"]=> string(19) "pthread mutex Locks" ["cache_list"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(11) { ["type"]=> string(4) "file" ["device"]=> int(0) ["inode"]=> int(0) ["filename"]=> string(59) "/path/web/app_clear.php" ["num_hits"]=> float(0) ["mtime"]=> int(1367935529) ["creation_time"]=> int(1367936893) ["deletion_time"]=> int(0) ["access_time"]=> int(1367936893) ["ref_count"]=> int(0) ["mem_size"]=> int(4240) } [1]=> array(11) { ["type"]=> string(4) "file" ["device"]=> int(0) ["inode"]=> int(0) ["filename"]=> string(53) "/path/web/app.php" ["num_hits"]=> float(6) ["mtime"]=> int(1367929750) ["creation_time"]=> int(1367936848) ["deletion_time"]=> int(0) ["access_time"]=> int(1367936888) ["ref_count"]=> int(0) ["mem_size"]=> int(8368) } } ["deleted_list"]=> array(0) { } ["slot_distribution"]=> array(2) { [10]=> int(1) [125]=> int(1) } } bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)
```

I am trying this:

```
  var_dump(apc_cache_info());
  var_dump(apc_clear_cache());
  var_dump(apc_clear_cache('tb_sf2'));
  var_dump(apc_clear_cache('user'));
  var_dump(apc_clear_cache('opcode'));
```

All the var_dumps are true.
The code is executed from php script by url hit.

BTW: my symfony2 front controller => app.php has die() at the top of script for disabling app for now.

How can I clear the cache?

Comment: This is not very clear. What result do you get from `var_dump(apc_clear_cache())`? Do you run it in from the CLI or in your code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: So if it returns true, your apc cache is cleared (http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php). Why do you think it is not?

Comment: Hm... in the output there is something what makes me suspicious: ["mem_size"]=> float(12608) or its ok?

Comment: Where and when do you get this output?

Comment: as i said ... i turned off my app. Then i went to the my file for clearing cache and made apc_cache_info()